# How to run es-lint rules on Vue component's external script files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, eslint, eslintrc

I've added es-lint checks on Vue components but the script for the component not in the same file, I kept it as a separate file for all the components in the project. For Example, I've added `vue/order-in-components` rule in `.eslintrc.js` which will throw an error if the component's script has the wrong order of hooks.

#### Correct Format:

```
export default {
  name: 'Address',
  props: {
    isNewRegistration: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      test: ''
    }
  }
}
```

#### Wrong Format:

```
export default {
  name: 'Address',
  // data should come after props
  data() {
    return {
      test: ''
    }
  }
  props: {
    isNewRegistration: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
```

Order in components documentation:
https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/order-in-components.html

As I've added the component's script through the external file. These checks are not happening while we run `eslint --fix`

Any solutions for this would be appreciated, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with vue but have you tried using `--ext` while running eslint like,

```
eslint --ext .vue --ext .js src/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using webpack template, add

```
preLoaders: { js: 'eslint-loader' }
```

to your vue-loader.conf.js file.